# How to display or not a NIB-created view based on a condition

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsview, nib

Currently, I have the following situation: I have a nib file that opens a menu, and has a unique main window. When this NIB-created view finishes the startup, the window is already initialized and displayed.

Besides starting the application with its normal way, I also want to start it in a particular way in which the window nor the menu are displayed.

I other words, I need to be able to define a condition at the startup of my application and based on that condition, I want to open/initialize/display the app using the normal view/nib or I want not to display them (but I may need to create/initialize the view).

Any ideas how can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the IB, go into the inspector and **turn off 'visible at launch' for the main window.**
THEN in your AppDelegate, check what to do: show the main window or make let it remain invisible and show the special window!

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification{
    if (myCondition == TRUE) {
       //do something else...
    } else {
        [[NSApp mainWindow] makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
    }
}
```